# R: how to use str_replace_all( ) without regular expression

Tags: r, text-processing

I have some textual data which contain "[surname]", "[female name]" and "[male name]". For example,

```
c("I am [female name]. I am ten years old", 
  "My father is [male name][surname]", 
  "I went to school today")
```

I hope to delete them for analysis and expect to get

```
"I am . I am ten years old", 
"My father is ", 
"I went to school today"
```

But when I run the code below, what it returns is broken. I think str_replace_all might recognize the pattern of [ ] as regular expressions, but I am not entirely sure why.

```
str_replace_all(c("I am [female name]. I am ten years old", 
                  "My father is [male name][surname]",
                  "I went to school today") , 
                "[surname]", '')

# [1] "I  [fl ]. I  t y old" "My fth i [l ][]"      "I wt to chool tody"
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try: `stringr::str_replace_all(c("I am [female name]. I am ten years old", "My father is [male name][surname]", "I went to school today") , stringr::fixed("[surname]"), '')`

Comment: Maybe `library(stringi)` and `stri_replace_all_fixed(x,c("[female name]", "[male name]", "[surname]"), '')`?

Comment: Or in *base*: `gsub("[surname]", "", c("I am [female name]. I am ten years old", "My father is [male name][surname]", "I went to school today"), fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: or `gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "", c("I am [female name]. I am ten years old", "My father is [male name][surname]", "I went to school today"))`

Comment: So, what is the point? Replace these three static (fixed) phrases only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stringi::str_replace_all`:

```r
library(stringi)
data <- c("I am [female name]. I am ten years old", "My father is [male name][surname]", "I went to school today") 
remove_us <- c("[female name]","[male name]","[surname]")
stri_replace_all_fixed(data, remove_us, "", vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

**Results**

```r
[1] "I am . I am ten years old" "My father is  "            "I went to school today"
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##VY/NCoJAFIX3PsVhVgrWE9SiRYFQq5YSctNrDoxO3Bkte3lTCcPduZeP8yPDYPRdSPrQedHNQ0dBQZ6w2yAPVQKqkZZck2E0VPNti/nnuUHPJA7WFCqGuvQoyVcs0A7pn09dK7OYoAQvbjy8hcsra82oCupVhEC4th1nrfsFrzJVrNL1tZhGwVQ7E34ayjkjY7JSv7kIpxExFtsxfCzQce6t6M8M7k@H8/UYBcPwBQ).

However, it is simpler with `gsub`:

```r
gsub('\\[[^][]*]', '', data)
```

See [another R proof](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwEEX3PcUnm2ixPUEv4KInGFOYmrEWEgNJRHL6VN108eHxeYsXa7WcGY8bxkb1YA@axLMTLOzF3HF@WRYU4ZgQnFUd1LNg4jxLxDeB/j6lNZ5wSD02WTJyQBrnENxOlotqcfmk9d3oYSB6GTJXozvofUdKW@sP).

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^][]*                   any character except: ']', '[' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```